# How to restrict user to view only specific buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a set of users: user1 and user2. Ideally they should have access to read and write in their own buckets.

I want to give them console access so they can login and upload the data in S3 through drag and drop.

So I want to the ability of one user to view buckets of other users.

I am using the following IAM policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::user1_bucket",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::user1_bucket/*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

But it does not show any bucket for the user. All the user can  see is *Access Denied* . 
I tried to add principal in the policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::9xxxxxxxxxx:user/user1"},
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::user1_bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This gives an error.

```
This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "it does not show any bucket for the user"? Are you saying that the user is unable to use the Amazon S3 management console to view their bucket?

Comment: When the user logs in to the AWS S3 management console he can only see *Access Denied*. No buckets are visible.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you want them to be able to do, and exactly what they should _not_ be able to do? For example, your goal might be "Allow users to list all buckets, allow users to view a list of objects in other buckets, but only allow users to upload to their specific bucket."

Comment: What I need is to let users login to their AWS account and view only the table they have access to. They should not have the right to *VIEW* tables that they do not have access to. What I have achieved so far is that the users can view all the tables but access only those they are supposed to. But i do not want them to view any other table than they are supposed to.

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean "bucket"? Or are you using Amazon Athena to query data stored in S3, thus you want to grant them access to Athena _tables_?

Comment: I am sorry I meant bucket

Comment: When you say "not want them to view any other table than they are supposed to", are you referring to viewing the listing _within_ the bucket, or viewing the fact that the bucket exists? To be able to use the Amazon S3 management console, users must be given sufficient permission to **list the names of all buckets**. You say that at the moment "users can view all the tables but access only those they are supposed to", so what exactly do you want to be different to that?

Comment: I do not want the users to list the name of all buckets. is it possibles ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your requirement is:

- Users should be able to use the Amazon S3 management console to access (view, upload, download) their own S3 bucket
- They should *not* be able to view the names of other buckets, nor access those buckets

**With listing buckets**

The first requirement can be met with a policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AccessThisBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListAllBucketForS3Console",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This allow them to access their specific bucket, but it also allows them to **list all bucket names**. This is a requirement of the Amazon S3 management console, since the first thing it does is list all of the buckets.

**Without listing buckets**

However, since you do not want to give these users the ability to list the names of all buckets, you could use a policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This gives them full access to their own bucket, but they cannot list the names of other buckets.

To use this in the management console, they will need to **jump directly to their bucket** using a URL like this:

```
https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/my-bucket
```

This will then allow them to access and use their bucket.

They will also be able to use [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) commands like:

```
aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

**Bottom line:** To use the management console without permission to list all buckets, they will need to use a URL that jumps straight to their bucket.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

**Bucket policies:** You select who can access and control said bucket, by attaching a policy. Example for your case:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "bucketAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Source: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Or you can give access through **role policies**, which I think is better. You almost had it, but you messed up at the end. Your policy should look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Source: [User Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex0)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This did not work for me. I still see Access Denied.

Comment: to reiterate the issue. I do not want the user to see/view other buckets. Accessing and reading/writing to specific buckets is not the problem. I am able to do that.

Comment: Okay have you tried granting the following policies:  
HeadBucket
ListAllMyBuckets
ListBucket
So far I can only assume it is some issue with the list rights. (These need a bucket arn)
 Try adding these to the policy and let me know ok?